# why won't this angular.js promise function fire in order?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, promise

The below function, getUserData(), i would expect the sequence of log statements to be whatever is returned from the firebase server for 'someusername' and then 1,2,3 but I am getting 1,2,3,-firebasereturninfo.  i can def see how the firebase return data and the 1 might be logged in a difference sequence but the 2 and 3 in my understanding of the promise object, should def not be getting called until the contents of the first .then closure is complete.  can someone guide me on this?  thanks!

```
getUserData: (participants) ->
  defer = $q.defer()
  defer.promise
    .then () ->
      Session.firebase.child("usernames/someusername").once "value", (userProfile) ->
        console.log userProfile.val()
      console.log "1"
    .then () ->
      console.log "2"
    .then () ->
      console.log "3"
  defer.resolve()
```

screenshot of console output.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem (or rather misunderstanding) is that [Firebase.once](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/firebase/once.html) is not invoking the callback function (given as its second param) immediately. Instead this function is assigned as a 'value' event handler in your case - but that event has nothing in common with promise you've set up earlier.

What you probably should do is put defer.resolve in the handler:

```
  defer = $q.defer()
  defer.promise
    .then () ->
      console.log "1"
    .then () ->
      console.log "2"
    .then () ->
      console.log "3"

  Session.firebase.child("usernames/someusername").once "value", (userProfile) ->
     console.log userProfile.val()
     defer.resolve()
```

Comment: interesting and I can set the .resolve to occur anywhere I want, and on top of that, I can have all kinds of promises resolving in different places based on callbacks?  this is like xmas and my bday together!

Comment: Well, yes, that's what they're for. ) The only restriction is that promise-holding object should be available in these callbacks (i.e., in their scope).

Comment: what do you think is a good way to handle this if I have a series of calls to make to the firebase server and once the last call has returned, invoke the .resolve() method ?

Comment: You might want to make a new SO question about this, but I'd take a look at https://github.com/mbostock/queue.